# set timer to do something in 10 minutes

Tags: android, timer, location

I want to save my location every 10 minutes,
I have code to get location from gps
then I want to save my location in database every 10 minutes
this is my code :

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    LocationManager locationManager;
    String context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(context);

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
    criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
    criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    updateWithNewLocation(null);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, (10*60*1000), 10,
                                           locationListener);
}
private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      updateWithNewLocation(location);
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
      updateWithNewLocation(null);
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){ }
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, 
                                Bundle extras){ }
  };
  public void updateWithNewLocation(Location location) {


        if (location != null) {
            Dbhelper helper = new Dbhelper(this);
            final SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss");
            final String curTime = df.format(time);
            final double lat = location.getLatitude();
            final double lng = location.getLongitude();
            final double alt = location.getAltitude();
            System.out.println(lat);
            System.out.println(lng);
            System.out.println(alt);
            /*db.execSQL("INSERT INTO location (longitude,latitude,altitude,tgl_buat) VALUES " +
            "('"+lng+"','"+lat+"','"+alt+"','"+curTime+"')");
            db.close();*/
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO location (longitude,latitude,altitude,tgl_buat) VALUES " +
                            "('"+lng+"','"+lat+"','"+alt+"','"+curTime+"')");
                    db.close();
                }
            }, 10*60*1000, 10*60*1000);

          } 
       }
```

but it's not working to save every 10 minutes..
how can I solved this??thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a handler to update at some point in the future:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html#concurrency_handler

Answer (score 0):

your location will really not be saved in the database because every time your location is updated (via `onLocationChanged(Location location)`), you are creating a new instance of your timer.

what you should do is bring your `timer` initialization in your `OnCreate()` method. then declare these variables

```
double lat = location.getLatitude();
double lng = location.getLongitude();
double alt = location.getAltitude();
```

as global and have them updated in the `onLocationChanged(Location location)` method. This way, whenever the timer calls on persistence in your database, the `lat, lng, alt` values will be available and be updated based on your latest location.

UPDATE:

here, you I fixed your code. can you try this?

```
//decalred as global variables
String curTime;
double lat;
double lng;
double alt;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    LocationManager locationManager;
    String context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(context);

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
    criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
    criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        //Initialize timer
        Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO location (longitude,latitude,altitude,tgl_buat) VALUES " +
                            "('"+lng+"','"+lat+"','"+alt+"','"+curTime+"')");
                    db.close();
                }
            }, 10*60*1000, 10*60*1000);


    updateWithNewLocation(null);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, (10*60*1000), 10,
                                           locationListener);
}
private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      updateWithNewLocation(location);
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
      updateWithNewLocation(null);
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){ }
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, 
                                Bundle extras){ }
  };
  public void updateWithNewLocation(Location location) {


        if (location != null) {
            Dbhelper helper = new Dbhelper(this);
            final SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss");
            curTime = df.format(time);
            lat = location.getLatitude();
            lng = location.getLongitude();
            alt = location.getAltitude();
            System.out.println(lat);
            System.out.println(lng);
            System.out.println(alt);

        } 

      }
```

Comment: what part it did not work? care to share more details? does it have any errors?

Comment: after few minutes i got error like this `FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
java.lang.IllegalStateException: database not open
` what happen with my code??thank you @stjom

Comment: call a `db.open()` before your `db.execute()`

Comment: my location can't insert into database too

Comment: my location can't insert into database too @stjom

Comment: what's the error? are you sure your variables lat,lng and alt have values?

Comment: try this:

`"INSERT INTO location (longitude,latitude,altitude,tgl_buat) VALUES " +
                            "("+lng+","+lat+","+alt+",'"+curTime+"')"`

i am assuming that the data types of lng, lat and alt are of numeric.

Comment: if my code put outside timer it's can inserted,but if i put inside timer it's not inserted..thank you :) @stjom